# UITextField return key next bug

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

There's explanation of question title

Here's part of code of InputViewController:

```
class InputViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    private var firstResponderTag = 0
    ...
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        firstResponderTag = textField.tag
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if let nextResponder = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1) {
            nextResponder.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        return true
    }
    ...
}
```

And SigningInViewController:

```
class SigningInViewController: InputViewController {
    ...
    @IBOutlet
    private weak var emailTextField: TextField! {
        didSet {
            emailTextField.validator = EmailValidator()
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet
    private weak var passwordTextField: TextField! {
        didSet {
            passwordTextField.validator = PasswordValidator()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Observable.combineLatest(emailTextField.rx_text, passwordTextField.rx_text, resultSelector: {
            (email: String, password: String) in
            email.length > 0 && password.length > 0
        }).bindTo(signInButton.rx_enabled).addDisposableTo(bag)
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem is that if I press return key `Next`, next text field becomes first responder and resigns first responder immediately. But if I remove binding return key works as it should. So, what do I make wrong?

**UPD:**

I've missed similar question in RxSwift's official repo.
**The solution is**

```
if let nextResponder = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1) {
    dispatch_async(dispath_get_main_queue(), {
        nextResponder.becomeFirstResponder()
    })
} else {
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @mohamede1945, yeah, I found it. You can see it in UPD section)

Answer (score 0):

I can not find the cause of error in your code, but I can share a code sample I just wrote recently.

```
class NextTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var returnView: UIView? {
        didSet {
            if returnView is UITextField {
                returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Next
            }
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        if let nextTextField = self.returnView as? UITextField {
            nextTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else if let nextButton = self.returnView as? UIButton {
            nextButton.sendActionsForControlEvents(.TouchUpInside)
        } else {
            self.resignFirstResponder()
        }

        return true
    }

}
```

It simply adds a weak returnView to the textField that can be easily set via code or storyboard. When the textfield's return key is pressed, it makes the firstresponder the returnView if it was an other textfield, touches the button if a button is the returnView and hides the keyboard if there is no returnView.

Comment: Unfortunately this code also works with bug as well as mine. But thank you for nice solution with `nextButton`. I think it's a bug within RxSwift/RxCocoa

Answer (score 0):

In Swift and RxSwift/RxCocoa 3.0.1

`placeTextField.rx.controlEvent(UIControlEvents.editingDidEndOnExit)`

works fine

instead of using `textFieldShouldReturn`